# Combinatorics about random strings

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A program generates random strings with $5$ letters which can be any of $a,g,j,o,x,y,z$ with repetitions allowed

How many different strings have two or more identical letters ?

I don’t understand the concept of two or more identical letters can someone explain?

Comment: What's the opposite? Five distinct letters. Seems easier to count.

Comment: Well, I guess that "$agjogz$" has a pair of identical letters since $g$ occurs twice, for example.

Comment: Yes. But you could have two double letters, or one triple letter, or... It's "two **or more**".

Comment: As a nitpick, I don't care if this question was asked in a class named "Probability."  The question itself is phrased as a counting question, not as a probability question, and so deserves the name and/or tag "Combinatorics."  It only becomes a probability question when you add on the final part "what is the *probability* that a randomly generated string has two or more identical letters"

Comment: Does “agjogz” count as having one identical letter?

Comment: Well *two* identical letters, or a double, yes.

Comment: As to your question, "agjogz" has one A, **two G's**, one J, one O, and one Z.  Two of the letters in it, the first G and the second G, are identical, hence it qualifies as being a string with two or more identical letters.  Rephrase it if you like as being a string which has at least one letter which is repeated more than once.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Two or more identical letters means that the strings can have two letters of $a,g,j,o,x,y$ or $z$ and/or three letters of $a,g,j,o,x,y$ or $z$ and/or ...

Here are some examples:

$agjoo, aaooo, jjaxy, xxxxx, ...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

To count the number of strings having more identical letters subtract the number of strings having all unique letters from the number all the possible strings.

To find all possible strings think how many different characters you may choose as the first letter, the second and so on.

To find all strings having unique letters (no two identical characters) find the number of different ways to choose $5$ characters out of your given alphabet and figure out in how many ways you can arrange these.

Hope this helped